# User Data from DynamoDB is rendered too late when calling it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, async-await, graphql

So I am trying to pull a users friendsList from a **dynamoDB**. I am using an **GraphQL API** to access my DB. In the commented out section of the code provided there I mention I have tried `users[1].friends.map`, which does return the correct friends list array, but users does not seem to get set until after the friends list has been rendered. How should I set up my code so the correct friends list (found in users) gets rendered the first time the page is rendered rather than after it gets updated??

```
const FriendsList = [
 {
    name: 'Name 1',

  },
  {
    name: 'Name 2',

  },
  {
    name: 'Name 3',

  }, 
  {
    name: 'Name 4',

  },
  {
    name: 'Name 5',

  },
  {
    name: 'Name 6',

  },
  
];
const Friends = (props) => {

  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = React.useState(false);
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);
  const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState(initialFormState);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserData();
   }, []);

  async function fetchUserData() {
    const userData = await API.graphql({ query: listUsers });
    setUsers(userData.data.listUsers.items);
  }


  //console.log(users);
    const renderFriendsList = (props) => {

    /* 
     *Here I want to have something like...
     * return users[1].friends.map((item, i) => {
     * so I can iterate through the friends list 
     */
    return FriendsList.map ((item, i) => {
        return (
          <View style={{ paddingLeft: scale(10), paddingRight: scale(10) }}>
            <View
              style={{
                backgroundColor: '#d1cfcf',
                width: scale(330),
                height: scale(85),
                borderRadius: scale(10),
                flexDirection: 'row',
                borderColor: '#8f8a8a',
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
              }}>

              <View>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>{item.name}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
    
    });
  };

    return (
      <View style={{}}>
          <View style={{ marginTop: scale(5) }}>
            {renderFriendsList()}
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

`fetchUserData()` should set `users` to the user data, but when I call users **before** the first time it renders, users is still undefined. If the application is running and has rendered the friends list from friendsList, and then I change it to users[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEWY6.png).friends on the fly, it works, but that is obviously is an issue because it does not render correctly the first time. I use the `React.useEffect()` and I figured that would call `fetchUserData()` when the page is rendered.

[image: Here is the output I am getting when I console.log(users.result)]
Here is the output I am getting when I `console.log(users.result)`

Comment: what does `userData.data.listUsers.items` contain? an object? an array?

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` with an empty array as argument gets called *after* the initial render, this is normal behaviour.

Usually when you want to render state related to an api call, you would store in the form of something like this:

```
const defaultState = { loading: false, result: null, error: null };
const [users, setUsers] = useState(defaultState);
```

Therefore you can do something like this:

```
async function fetchUserData() {
    setUsers({ ...defaultState, loading: true });
    try {
        const userData = await API.graphql({ query: listUsers });
        setUsers({ ...defaultState, result: userData.data.listUsers.items});
    } catch (e) {
        setUsers({ ...defaultState, error: e.message });
    };
}
```

Since you're making a remote call it makes sense to show a spinner during the load time, rather than immediately rendering the collection.
Therefore you can use the `loading` property on the state object for this purpose.

Of course there are other techniques where you immediately make the ajax call at the server, and either push them as json to the client immediately, or just render the html from the server.

Edit:
Based on the current solution you can do:

```
... 
return (
    <>
        { loading && <>loading...</> }
        {
            !loading
            && result 
            && <FriendList result={ result } /> // map now that the results are available 
        }
    </>
)
```

Comment: user.result producsed:  ```null
Array [
  Object {
    "createdAt": "2022-02-08T16:49:48.054Z",``` is what I am getting, and I cant access the object in the array. The array is in users.results, and I can't use users.results[1] (which is the array object I want to access),  and I think it is because of the null object before the array.

Comment: @trash_Panda Could you please make a screenshot and add it to your question? I don't really understand the result you're observing.

Comment: I added a picture to the question

Comment: @trash_Panda Yes it's normal that it is null the first time, because loading will be true... loading indicates you're making the network request, and the result will only be available when it arrives from the network. You could do something in your jsx like `users.results && users.results.length > 0 && <List />`.

Comment: @trash_Panda Check my edit for solution.

Comment: where do I put that code you just edited in your solution? I put it inside the fetchUserData() function, but FriendsLsit still isnt changing. And would I still want to FriendsList.map? Im thinking yes because friendsList should get set with the result, but could I map from users?

Comment: @trash_Panda That edit is just the return JSX from the functional component.