# Using the Amplify Graphql Client in Javascript to Query Data

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, graphql

On the API(GraphQL) - Getting Started documentation [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/query-data/q/platform/js/#query-declarations), it says to query your data using the following:

```
import { API } from 'aws-amplify';
import * as queries from './graphql/queries';

// Simple query
const allTodos = await API.graphql({ query: queries.listTodos });
console.log(allTodos); // result: { "data": { "listTodos": { "items": [/* ..... */] } } }
```

However, when I try to apply their code to my javascript code it says that it does not recognize the word **await**. Online it says I can only use the **await** keyword inside of a async function. When I take the await keyword out, the promise from the query function does not get settled so it returns the promise first before the data.

I tried setting up an async function before, and posted a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71200306/user-data-from-dynamodb-is-rendered-too-late-when-calling-it) about it. The solution got a little messy, and did not quite work for me. So, I am wondering what is the best way to go about querying data using Graphql? And how do I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

`await` can be used only with in an `async` context, so ideally what you would have to do is the following

```
const allTodos = async () => {
   const todos = await API.graphql({ query: queries.listTodos }); 
   return todos
}
```